# Convert MATLAB Code to Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration, code-review, matlab

I have written a MATLAB code as following, in order to calculate an integration involving *Modified Bessel Function* with *variable limits*:

```
function num_exact_JD()
    rho = 0.5 * ones(1, 5); 
    N = 4; 
    sigma = ones(1, 5); 

    Omega = sigma .* sqrt((1 - rho.^2) / 2); 
    R_c = 0.5; 

    sys_SNR_dB = -5:2:25; 
    sys_SNR = 10.^(sys_SNR_dB / 10); 

    out_probs = zeros(1, size(sys_SNR, 2)); 

    for i = 1:size(sys_SNR, 2)
    out_probs(i) = outage_prob(rho, sys_SNR(i), Omega, sigma, N, R_c);
    end

end

function res = phi(r)
    res = log10(r + 1) / log(2);
end

function res = outage_prob(rho, snr, omega, sigma, N, R_c)

    fac = snr / N;

    f = @(om, gam, sig, R, lam) 1/(2*om^2*fac) * ...
        exp(-(gam/fac+(lam*sig*R).^2)./(2*om^2)) .* ...
        besseli(0, sqrt(gam/fac)*lam*sig*R./om^2); 

    f1 = @(g4, g3, g2, g1, R) f(omega(1), g1, sigma(1), R, rho(1)) .* ...
        f(omega(2), g2, sigma(2), R, rho(2)) .* ...
        f(omega(3), g3, sigma(3), R, rho(3)) .* ...
        f(omega(4), g4, sigma(4), R, rho(4));

    m1 = @(g3, g2, g1, R) integral(@(g4) f1(g4, g3, g2, g1, R),...
        0, 2.^(R_c-phi(g1)-phi(g2)-phi(g3))-1, 'ArrayValued',true);

    m2 = @(g2, g1, R) integral(@(g3) m1(g3, g2, g1, R),...
        0, 2.^(R_c-phi(g1)-phi(g2))-1, 'ArrayValued',true);

    m3 = @(g1, R) integral(@(g2) m2(g2, g1, R),...
        0, 2.^(R_c-phi(g1))-1, 'ArrayValued',true);

    m4 = @(R) integral(@(g1) m3(g1, R), 0, 2.^(R_c)-1, 'ArrayValued',true) 
        *2.*exp(-R.^2).*R;

    res = integral(@(R) m4(R), 0, 20);

end
```

It costs lots of time to execute, so I'd like to convert it to Mathematica and check whether it'll run faster. The following is the corresponding Mathematica code:

```
num = 4;
rho = 0.5*Table[1, num];
sigma = Table[1, num];
omega = sigma*Sqrt[0.5*(1 - rho^2)];
r = 0.5;
snr = 10^(Table[i, {i, -5, 25, 2}]/10);
probs = Table[0, 16];

phi[r_] := Log[r + 1]/Log[2];

fac = snr[1]/num;

f[om, gam, sig, y, lam] := 1/(2*om^2*fac)*Exp[-(gam/fac + 
   (lam*sig*y)^2)/(2*om^2)]*BesselI[0, Sqrt[gam/fac*lam*sig*y/om^2]];

f1[g4, g3, g2, g1, y] := f[omega[[1]], g1, sigma[[1]], y, rho[[1]]]*
   f[omega[[2]], g2, sigma[[2]], y, rho[[2]]]*
   f[omega[[3]], g3, sigma[[3]], y, rho[[3]]]*
   f[omega[[4]], g4, sigma[[4]], y, rho[[4]]];

m1[y] := Integrate[f1, {g4, 0, 2^(r - phi[g1] - phi[g2] - phi[g3]) - 1}, 
   {g3, 0, 2^(r - phi[g1] - phi[g2]) - 1}, {g2, 0, 2^(r - phi[g1]) - 1}, 
   {g1,0, 2^(r) - 1}];

m4 = Integrate[m1*2*Exp[-y^2]*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

First, I don't know how to convert the for-loop part, so in the Mathematica code I just write down the first iteration. Moreover, I know the multiple dimensional integration is wrong, but I get stuck in this.

Could anyone check my Mathematica code and give me some suggests? Thanks very much indeed!

Answer (score 3):

This is how the code looks after some adjustments. In some of the function declarations, you missed the underscore `_`. Moreover, I changed the argument pattern of `m1` to `y_?NumericQ` in order to prevent the `NIntegrate` in the definition of `m4` from trying to evaluate `m1[y]` symbolically. Note that I used `NIntegrate`, not `Integrate`. Moreover, `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"` speeds up the `m1` (`m1[1.]` needs about `2.7` seconds to evaluate). I haven't tried to evaluate `m4`. It will take *very* long.

```
num = 4;
ρ = Table[0.5, num];
σ = Table[1., num];
ω = σ Sqrt[0.5 (1 - ρ^2)];
r = 0.5;
snr = 10.^(Table[i, {i, -5, 25, 2}]/10);
probs = Table[0, 16];
ϕ[r_] := Log[r + 1]/Log[2];

fac = snr[[1]]/num;

f[ω_, γ_, σ_, y_, λ_] :=  1/(2 ω^2 fac) Exp[-(γ/fac + (λ σ y)^2)/(2 ω^2)] BesselI[0, Sqrt[γ/fac λ σ y/ω^2]];
f1[g_, y_] := Times @@ MapThread[f[#1, #2, #3, y, #4] &, {ω, g, σ, ρ}];

m1[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
   f1[{g1, g2, g3, g4}, y],
   {g1, 0, 2^(r) - 1},
   {g2, 0, 2^(r - ϕ[g1]) - 1},
   {g3, 0, 2^(r - ϕ[g1] - ϕ[g2]) - 1},
   {g4, 0, 2^(r - ϕ[g1] - ϕ[g2] - ϕ[g3]) - 1},
   Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"
   ];

m4 = NIntegrate[m1[y] 2 Exp[-y^2]*y, {y, 0, ∞}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, when I run your code, the output is `NIntegrate[m1[y] 2 Exp[-y^2] y, {y, 0, 15}]` rather than a certain value. And a Warning would come out that pointed out the calculation of integrand will get a NaN. Does the problem locate in that the multi-dimensional integral order was reversed?